# Process Explorer hangs after symbols have been configured

Tags: windows, process-explorer, symbols

I have configured symbols in Process Explorer. I am aware that this has an impact on the performance of Process Explorer, especially in the beginning when symbols have not been downloaded from Microsoft yet.

However, in this case, I was already waiting for more than 20 minutes for symbols being downloaded and still Process Explorer is displayed as "not responding" by Windows.

Of course I have checked the symbol path syntax multiple times. a) I can see that some symbols have been downloaded, since folders and files appeared in the symbol cache directory which was empty before. b) I have even copied the symbol path from WinDbg where it worked.

What else could make Process Explorer not responding?

Using Process Explorer 16.21, which seems to be the latest release.

Comment: I'd probably take a dump of procexp64.exe with Process Explorer and analayze the threads in Windbg. :) Seriously, you can run `procdump64.exe -ma -mk procexp64.exe` to get a user and kernel mode dump of the process.  What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: @HelpingHand: yes, maybe I'll analyze it in WinDbg myself. I'd appreciate not - but well ... I can give exact Windows version tomorrow when I'm at work.